Can I use Sqlite json functions like 'json_extract' with better-sqlite3?
Is it possible to use Sqlite json functions like 'json_extract' with better-sqlite3 ? If possible how can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

console.log(db.prepare("select json_extract('[1]', '$[0]')").all()); works for me with the latest better-sqlite3. Does it not work for you?

Thanks. It works with latest better-sqlite3. Though I have decided to use a separate table instead of using json field, since json field can make some overhead in my query.  My schema is structured for now and I can use a separate table.
